# Migrating existing rails app from SQLite to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql

I saw some of the tutorials on how to migrate from sqlite to postgresql, but it is either for mac or it is for a new/fresh app. What if I already have an App with data sqlite in it. I am using rails 3.2.2 and windows 7. Anyone knows which is the best way to migrate sqlite to postgresql? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erm, if in development ,u re using sqlite and maybe you have to deploy to heroku, then it is just changing the gem for database. But the data will be blank, if you want to total migrate with data, I guess you have to dump the data and load it in postgresql

Comment: it is actually fine if the data will be blank. since my data is not that big. I can add it later. But the tables will be there right?
So, do you mean I just have to add gem postresql?

Comment: ya, you can just insert to rake db:migrate and everything will be there.

Comment: Sorry, but I did that all and there are my tables. But.. I can't create my posts anymore. Can't understand